# Overhead of Using EventListener vs Polling

Tags: video, actionscript, streaming, buffering

So I have streaming video coming in, and I want to know when it is buffering.  This is fundamentally not that hard, just adding an EventListener for some type of buffering event, but I was wondering if this is necessarily the "best" way to do it.

My other thought was setting up a timer that polls the video feed every X milliseconds asking it if the video isBuffering(), or somesuch.  While I could, in the worst case, wait the full X milliseconds before querying the video stream, I've decided that this doesn't *actually* matter to me; I can work around it, and indeed do so quite naturally already.

So I'm asking: is there substantial overhead involved in having an EventListener (assuming I already have quite a few), or is the advantage of catching the buffering event right away sufficiently appealing?

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to the eventListener.
Although, You can avoid buffering if you dynamically change the video on the fly to a lower quality video.

Comment: Surely that's not a 100% guarantee to avoid buffering, though?  Somehow I think I'm always going to have to accommodate for buffering, since there are such a multitude of things that will force it.